# How to get the ScreenX event of a container in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hi i'm trying to get the screenX event(e.screenX) when the pointer moves on a container/image.

Once i get the screenX value it should show "i'm Left" if < 50% and show "i'm Right" if >=50%.

I've tried to get the screenX but i'm getting the console.log as "undefined" and not a value.

Below is my code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";


 function useScreenX() {
 const [screenPosition, setScreenPosition] = useState(0);

 function handleDocument() {
  const { screenX: currentScreenX } = document.querySelector("#screen-log");     // I'm doing something wrong here//

 setScreenPosition(currentScreenX);

 console.log(currentScreenX);


}

  useEffect(() => {
     window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleDocument);

    return () =>
     window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleDocument);
   }, []);

   return (
       <div id="screen-log">
        <h1>My Container</h1>
       </div>
          );
     }

       export default useScreenX;



     CSS Style:
           #screen-log {
                 background-color: gold;
                 width: 100vw;
                 height: 200px;
                       }
```

Comment: You need to add the `event` argument to the handler function `function handleDocument(event)...` then get the properties of that event object

Comment: Yeah.. you are correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Just few minor corrections to make:

1. you should use the event in your `handleDocument`
2. screenX returns a number and you are trying to store it as an object
3. you need mouse movements to be tracked on specific div but you are attaching the listener to the entire window.

The `handleDocument` function automatically get's the event object. Use it to get `screenX`. Also obtain the element in `useEffect` and attach the listener to the element.

[Working copy of your code is here in the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mouse-move-event-handler-fix-1hr6w)

Code Snippet:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [screenPosition, setScreenPosition] = useState(0);

  function handleDocument(e) {
    const screenX = e.screenX;
    setScreenPosition(screenX);
    console.log(screenX);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document
      .getElementById("screen-log")
      .addEventListener("mousemove", handleDocument);

    return () =>
      document
        .getElementById("screen-log")
        .removeEventListener("mousemove", handleDocument);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="screen-log">
      <h1>My Container</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much... you explained it so nice and your answer has really made me to move ahead.Thank you.!!